# is it possible to skip this event captured when clicked on Inner div

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery collapsable set for my Application .

when clicked on the (Header element (**Bottle** in this case))TreeMenu class i am able to capture the event using collapsibleexpand .

But is it possible to skip this event capture whenclikecd on its sub elemnt (**200 ML** and **300 ML**) in my case ??

http://jsfiddle.net/u8fjv78s/1/

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper" id="datacontainer">
   <div class="TreeMenu ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
      <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a" aria-hidden="false">

          <div class="TreeMenuChild ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true"></div>
         </div>

         <div class="TreeMenuChild ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-a ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

$(document).on('collapsibleexpand', '.TreeMenu', function(){   

    alert('sss');

});
```

please let me know how to do this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter it regarding event target class:

```
$(document).on('collapsibleexpand', '.TreeMenu', function(e){ 
    if($(e.target).hasClass('TreeMenuChild')) return; // skip it
    alert('sss');
});
```

### -jsFiddle-